# Redirect all non-www to www for both http and https with .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect all non-www to www - if the request is through http it should redirect to http://www.domain.com, if the request is through https then direct to https://www.domain.com

I have tried the following in my .htaccess, but it redirects everything to https

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301
```

---

I have used this code and it's resolving perfectly. Please check whether it's correct or not.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#Redirect non-www to www

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.pnrstatusbuzz.in/%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this rule as your **first rule**:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: After a lot of trial & error this one worked for me as well. Thanks a lot!